# Remove texture coordinates from fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, opengl-es-2.0

I have a vertex and fragment shader and I want to show a solid color instead of a texture.

I have the following vertex and fragment shader.

```
static const char* meshVertexShader = " \
  \
attribute vec4 vertexPosition; \
attribute vec4 vertexNormal; \
attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord; \
 \
varying vec2 texCoord; \
varying vec4 normal; \
 \
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix; \
 \
void main() \
{ \
   gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertexPosition; \
   normal = vertexNormal; \
   texCoord = vertexTexCoord; \
} \
";


static const char* fragmentShader = " \
 \
precision mediump float; \
 \
varying vec2 texCoord; \
varying vec4 normal; \
 \
uniform sampler2D texSampler2D; \
 \
void main() \
{ \
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord); \
} \
";
```

How can I must modify fragment shader to not show a texture? (sorry for my english).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord);
```

to

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1,1,1,1);
```

It will draw white colour instead of the texture.

Comment: Which obviously also means that you can cut all references to texCoord and texSampler2D if you wish, but probably the compiler would eliminate them automatically anyway.